# How can I use comix to open image folders together?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-viewers

I have an album containing many image folders. I want to watch them using comix directly, but unfortunately I must open each folder one by one. How can I open them together with comix?

Alternatively, are there any image viewers that can auto-resize images with easy navigation that can open images in multiple folders together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compress the album into a .rar or a .zip file. You can already open it with comix but for an even better result rename (you only have to change the extension of the file) the resulting .rar (to .cbr) or .zip (to .cbz)
Myfolder.rar --> Myfolder.cbr

Comment: it worked thanks. but i need more storages for this one.